# Fourier cosine series for $\cos x$

Tags: fourier-series

I was trying to find the Fourier cosine series of the function $\cos x$ in $[0, \pi]$. But I am getting all $a_n$ zero. How to proceed?

Comment: Can you show your development ?

Comment: You sure the terms are #all# zero?  Doesn't the product cos $mx$ cos $nx$ have a different sort of antiderivative when $m=n$ versus otherwise?

Comment: @Lanzi Sorry, I overlooked the case when $m=n$. Now I got $a_1=1$  and other $a_i$'s are zero.

Comment: Note that if you approximate $f(x)$ with some collection of functions that includes $f(x)$ then it perfectly approximates itself.

Answer (score 3):

$\cos\left(x\right)$ is itself a basis vector, so without any calculation you already know there is exactly one non-zero coefficient and its value is $1$... You can find that coefficient with a glance at the basis (and its numbering).

Answer (score 1):

This question seems to have been answered in effect in comments, but here the answer is fleshed out in the "answer" section.

Under [what seems to be the usual interpretation of a "Fourier cosine series"](http://www.sosmath.com/fourier/fourier2/fourier2.html),
you treat the region of integration $[0,\pi]$ as just one half of the period of a periodic function, with the other half defined by the assumption that the function is even.
When you have an even function with period $2\pi$ such as $\cos x,$ its Fourier cosine series on $[0,\pi]$ is identical to the Fourier series of the function on $[-\pi,\pi],$ which in turn can be computed by integrating over just the interval $[0,\pi].$ At least that's how I look at it.

The formula for the coefficients of the series (as shown [in Wolfram Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierCosineSeries.html), for example), is
$$
  a_n = \frac2\pi \int_0^\pi f(x)\cos(n x) dx,
$$
and setting $f(x) = \cos x,$ this formula gives $a_1 = 1.$

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget the sine terms:

\begin{align*}
  f(x+2L) &= f(x) \\
  f(x) &=\frac{a_{0}}{2}+
         \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}
           \left(
             a_{n}\cos \frac{n\pi x}{L}+
             b_{n}\sin \frac{n\pi x}{L}
           \right) \\
  a_{n} &= \frac{1}{L}\int_{0}^{2L} f(t)\cos \frac{n\pi t}{L} dt \\
        &= \frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi} \cos t \cos (2nt) dt \\
        &= 0 \\
  b_{n} &= \frac{1}{L}\int_{0}^{2L} f(t)\sin \frac{n\pi t}{L} dt \\
        &= \frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi} \cos t \sin (2nt) dt \\
        &= \frac{8n}{(4n^{2}-1)\pi}
\end{align*}

Comment: "Fourier _cosine_ series" implies a different formula, with $\cos(nt)$ instead of $\cos(t).$ See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierCosineSeries.html